# Converting units, for the magnetic moment

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, units, magnetic-moment, unit-conversion

I found, that magnetic moment is measured by $\rm J/T$, and  equals magnetization times volume:
$$\vec{m}=\vec{M}V$$

Magnetization, also equals magnetic susceptibility times external magnetic field:
$$\vec{M}=\chi\vec{H}$$

$\chi$ doesn’t have units, $\vec{H}$ has $\rm T$. How does equation below, gives $\rm J/T$ units?

$$\vec{m}= \chi\vec{H}V= \rm T\cdot m^3$$

Answer (score 0):

The unit of magnetic moment $\mathbf{m}$ is [J/T] or equivalently [Nm$^2$]. The unit of the magnetic field $\mathbf{H}$ and the magnetization $\mathbf{M}$ is the same [A/m]. The unit of the magnetic induction $\mathbf{B}$ is [T]. The relation between these quantities is
$$\mathbf{M} = \frac{\mathbf{m}}{V}$$
$$ \mathbf{B}= \mu_0(\mathbf{H}+\mathbf{M})$$
with $\mu_0$ the vacuum permeability with unit [N/A$^2$].

Comment: The units for the magnetic moment **m** in Frederic's answer should be [A m^2].